Konsole problems
By trying to resolve some Konsole problems
in Ubuntu 22.04, I have replaced the default
command in the new test profile with: source .login
because my .login file was ignored by Konsole.
After I made this profile default, however,
Konsole fails to open any window at all.
How can I rectify this? Can I remove
the Konsole software completely
to then reinstall it again?
Thanks for any help.

I have just tried to reinstall Konsole:
sudo apt install konsole
and got a Konsole that works just fine,
as in 18.04 I was used to. It does not
even require any readjustment and creation
of a new profile. So it seems that the
Konsole I had originally on the new computer
was some different very user-unfriendly
version. It did not permit
any /usr/bin/command:
bash: /usr/bin/command: Permission denied
In addition, my .login file, where some commands
are redefined, was ignored by it. This created
the problem I reported above.
Also, cd command returned me to /home/naftali/snap/konsole/36 originally
defined by Konsole rather than to /home/naftali I defined as the
initial directory in the new Default profile created by me.
All this did work properly in other types of terminals without any
readjustments, including in Terminal itself. All this also used to
work so in the Ubuntu 18.04 Konsole. In particular, all commands
in /usr/bin are permitted to be executed by anyone. So it seems
I just had to reinstall konsole. This also answers my previous
question on Konsole.
